# Javascript function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm at that point in the day where I have the simplest bloody issue but can't see it.

To save me losing all my hair and crying in the shower, I'm asking this question.

WHY WON'T THE CONFIRM BOX APPEAR.

```
$(document).on('click', '.create_btn', function() {

if (confirm('Are you sure you want to create this user?')) {
} else {
    return false;
}

ShowCreateLoadingScreen("Creating...");
AjaxHandler('library/ajax/ajax.admin-account-create.php', data, 'POST', true);
});
```

There's my JS, here's my input.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="span3"><input type="text" name="ausername" id="ausername" class="span12" placeholder="Username" value="%enteredUsername%"></div>
<div class="span3"><input type="text" name="aemail" id="aemail" class="span12" placeholder="Email" value="%enteredEmail%"></div>
<div class="span3"><input type="password" name="apassword" id="apassword" class="span12" placeholder="Password"></div>
<div class="span3 admin-product-actions">
<input type="submit" name="create" class="btn create-btn btn-success span12" title="Create Account" value="Create Account">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Any errors reported in the console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace `create_btn` by `create-btn`

```
$(document).on('click', '.create-btn', function()
```

Comment: hahaaa sharp eyes. +1

Comment: @user3393100 or need to go to the ophthalmologist... ;)

Comment: I have to wait 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an event handler on `create_btn`but your actual class is `create-btn`. Change this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.create_btn', function() {
```

to this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.create-btn', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your click handler is not quite correct,

You can simply change your click handler to

```
$('.create-btn').click(function ( event ) {
...
});
```

and in my opinion it should work then.